# error: cannot assign to immutable indexed content `i[..]`

Tags: rust

In the following rust code I am trying to change the contents of an array:

```
    let mut example_state = [[0;8]; 2];
    for mut i in example_state.iter() {
        let mut k = 0;
        for j in i.iter(){
            i[k] = 9u8;
            k +=1
        }
    }
```

However I get the error message:

```
src/main.rs:18:13: 18:23 error: cannot assign to immutable indexed content `i[..]`
src/main.rs:18             i[k] = 9u8;
```

which I'm confused by because I am defining `i` to be `mut` and `example_state` is also mutable.

I also don't know if this is the best way to change the contents of an array - do I need the counter `k` or can I simply use the iterator `j` in some way?

**UPDATE:**
So I found that this block of code works:

```
let mut example_state = [[n;8]; 2];
for i in example_state.iter_mut() {
    for j in i.iter_mut(){
        *j = 9u8;
    }
}
```

but I would appreciate some explanation of what the difference is between them, `iter_mut` doesn't throw up much on Google.

Comment: Isn't all that code simply `let example_state = [[9u8; 8]; 2]` ?

Comment: It's a simplified example of something more complicated - I'm trying to understand why *this* doesn't work.

Comment: Fair enough. It's a good question regardless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at the signatures of the two methods, [`iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter) and [`iter_mut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.iter_mut):

```
fn iter(&self) -> Iter<T>;
fn iter_mut(&mut self) -> IterMut<T>;
```

And the structs they return, [`Iter`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html) and [`IterMut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.IterMut.html), specifically the implementation of `Iterator`:

```rust
// Iter
type Item = &'a T
// IterMut
type Item = &'a mut T
```

These are *associated types*, but basically in this case, they specify what the return type of calling `Iterator::next`. When you used `iter`, even though it was on a mutable variable, you were asking for an iterator to *immutable references* to a type `T` (`&T`). That's why you weren't able to mutate them!

When you switched to `iter_mut`, the return type of `Iterator::next` is `&mut T`, a *mutable reference* to a type `T`. You are allowed to set these values!

As an aside, your question used *arrays*, not *slices*, but there aren't documentation links for arrays (that I could find quickly), and slices are close enough to arrays so I used them for this explanation.

Comment: how do you check a method signature?

Comment: @MikeVella I just refer to the [documentation](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/) which has a comprehensive search feature. Rustdoc is actively being worked on, so sometimes I do have to go [source diving](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust). Then it's just a matter of looking for `fn my_name`!

Answer (score 4):

There are two orthogonal concepts going on here:

- Whether the *reference itself* is mutable. That's the difference between `i` and `mut i`.
- Whether the *data it points to* is mutable. That's the difference between `.iter()`/`&T` and `.iter_mut()`/`&mut T`.

If you use C, this distinction should be familiar. Your initial code creates *mutable references* to *immutable data*, or `const char *` in C. So while you can assign to the reference itself (`i = ...`), you can't modify the data it points to (`*i = ...`). That's why the compiler stops you.

On the other hand, your fixed code creates *immutable references* to *mutable data*. That's `char * const` in C. This doesn't let you assign to the reference itself, but it does let you modify the underlying array, so it compiles as expected.

---

So why does Rust have a separate `.iter()` and `.iter_mut()`? Because in Rust, while you can take as many `&T` to a structure as you want, you can only modify it through a single `&mut T`. In other words, mutable references are unique and never [alias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing).

Having both `.iter()` and `.iter_mut()` gives you a choice. On one hand, you can have any number of immutable iterators in scope at once, all pointing to the same array. Here's a silly example that iterates forwards and backwards at the same time:

```
for i, j in array.iter().zip(array.iter().rev()) {
    println!("{} {}", i, j);
}
```

But if you want a mutable iterator, you have to guarantee the references never alias. So this won't work:

```
// Won't compile
for i, j in array.iter_mut().zip(array.iter_mut().rev()) {
    println!("{} {}", i, j);
}
```

because the compiler can't guarantee `i` and `j` don't point to the same location in memory.